# Error : "class expected"

Tags: java, casting, compiler-errors, int, double

Well ,I find this a very petty concern , though I'm not able to get through it.
I have been through so many questions here, but no one was of exact help.

I am trying to type cast a `double` value to `int` in following way :

```
int res=int(Math.pow(2,3));
```

and it throws a `error: '.class' expected` .

Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What do you think `int(..)` does and why do you think so?

Comment: int res=(int)Math.pow(5, 6);

Comment: `Math.pow(2,3)` results to `8.0` , double type value. So `int(Math.pow(2,3))` must result into an int type value. In fact , this is what I have found wherever I have seen.

Comment: if I'm wrong , please correct me . Thanks